# Include single lines of php in ordered list

Tags: php

I am fairly new to php and not sure if it is possible to include php file content line by line.

Say I have an ordered list and a php file with three lines. I can include the whole content using
 `<?php include 'myfile.php' ?>`

my question is, if it is possible to include single lines.

**myfile.php**

```
  apples
  bananas
  oranges
```

**index.php**

```
<ol>
 <li>???????</li>
 <li>???????</li>
 <li>???????</li>
</ol>
```

Thanks

Comment: take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: You're looking for [`file()`](http://php.net/file) and [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more possibilities one of them is to put your content in a text file and load the content with `file` for example. Then you can iterate through every line with foreach.

The other way is to put your values in an array if your don't need it in a file.

```
$fruits = array(
  'apples',
  'bananas',
  'oranges'
);
```

Then you can iterate with foreach over that array.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Before you start you should read about that things and perhaps you start at the beginning of that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the file as an array:

```
$myFile = file('myfile.php', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES strips the new line characters from the array
```

now you can either print a single line:

```
echo $myFile[2]; // echo the third item
```

or output everything as a HTML list:

```
echo '<ol>';
foreach ($myFile as item) {
  echo '<li>'. $item .'</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in various ways: 
declaring variables for each one:

**myfile.php**

```
<?php
$apples = "apples";
$bananas = "bananas";
$oranges = "oranges";
```

and print them in the list:

**index.php**

```
<ol>
 <li><?php echo $apples; ?></li>
 <li><?php echo $bananas; ?></li>
 <li><?php echo $oranges; ?></li>
</ol>
```

**OR** declaring one array with all of them.

**myfile.php**

```
<?php
$fruits = array( 'apples', 'bananas', 'oranges' );
```

and print them in the list using a foreach:

**index.php**

```
<ol>
<?php
foreach ($fruits as $fruit){
   echo '<li>'.$fruit.'</li>';
}
?>
</ol>
```

Good Luck!